# Dump/inspect running PyPy process

Tags: python, debugging, centos, gdb, pypy

I have a `PyPy` (v  4.0.1) process running in production on CentOS 7.
The process seems to have gotten into a bad state.

Is there a way to inspect the process live? i.e. attach an interpreter to it and inspect certain variables? Or maybe look at the values of some modules?

OR.

Is there a way to dump the state of the process so it can be loaded up locally to make debugging easier?

I've attempted to follow the instructions given https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb but haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: I guess you're asking for a way to debug your Python program?  There are ways, they are not specific to PyPy and don't involve gdb.  Or you're asking about ways to debug the PyPy virtual machine which shows random crashes that are not directly due to your program doing bad things?  In that case I'd recommend first upgrading to a more recent version than 4.0.1 and seeing if the problem occurs again.

Comment: Thanks @ArminRigo. But the process is running so I can't upgrade it, or do the other usual debug things i'm used to.  

Reproducing the bug isn't easy so i'd rather be able to debug the process thats already running than add debug tools to it, restart it, and hope to see the bug again.

Comment: But i can see why this may not be possible depending on how the VM/JIT actually works.

Comment: I still don't really understand the point.  Say you were talking about CPython instead of PyPy; would there be something you'd be able to do in this case?

Comment: I want to use something like https://github.com/google/pyringe or https://pyrasite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html, if that helps clarify what i mean.

Comment: Thanks for the precision!  There is nothing I know about.  We could try to adapt these tools (which are based on a hack with gdb), e.g. to call the functions ``PyPyGILState_Ensure()`` etc. instead of ``PyGILState_Ensure()``.  Or we can think about doing a clean solution directly inside any PyPy---something like, you'd send it a certain signal and it would open a debugging socket.  If you're interested in that solution, come and discuss it on #pypy, irc.freenode.net, and we can try to implement it :-)

Comment: As I had suspected. Thanks a ton @ArminRigo.

Comment: pyrasite might work out of the box if you replace the three calls to 'PyXxx' functions with 'PyPyXxx' functions, in pyrasite.injector.inject.  I didn't try, but I tried to manually run a gdb that attaches to a pypy process, and call these functions: ``PyPyRun_SimpleString("print 5")`` works.